# How do I clear an aggressive cache when I can't even find *where* it's being cached?

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have a Wordpress site, and a very strange problem.  I have a page on that site that has pictures on it.  I edited the HTML directly to refer to the picture files in a certain place in the directory structure on the hosted site.

I then went in, via SFTP, and deleted *one* photo on the site because I need to alter the original.

Browsing to the page, however, shows that photo still there.  No amount of cache clearing (Google Chrome, IE, and Firefox) will resolve the issue.  I also use ipconfig /flushdns repeatedly.

How can a page show a picture file that's not there?  It's driving me batty!  I don't even know where to begin to look to solve this problem....

Comment: have you deleted the correct image? wordpress makes thumbnails of the image and display these if the theme use it

Comment: Yes, I have.  wp-content/uploads is the only directory WordPress recognizes.  I have a 'Photos' directry underneath that, and several other directories underneath that...   I edit the HTML to refer directly to the location to display the file.

Comment: it might be your hosts cache - have you checked the source code, to see what path it takes the image from?

Comment: The host is GoDaddy, and they have an option in a Wordpress site where I can direct the cache to be flushed.

The HTML is edited directly by me.  It's pointing directly to the proper path where the file used to be before I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `?v=1.123` at the end of your url and see the problem is solve or not.

Comment: What does that do that ?nocache=1 doesn't do?, and yes, I did it, and no it did not solve the problem.  The photo still shows, even though it isn't there.

Comment: add this will leads the browser to think as it's a new path and then the browser load it from new.......best way to see weather it's a cache problem or not.

Comment: but isn't that what ?nocache=1 does anyway?